# Split SQL insert statement into key-value pairs

Tags: python, regex

Given the following statement as a string

```
stmt = "insert into table (col1, col2, col3) values (100, '() string with parantheses ()', 2.3);"
```

I am trying to find a regular expression (or any other way if there is a better one) to split that string into a list `["(col1, col2, col3)", "(100, '() string with parantheses ()', 2.3)"]` such that I can later fill a dicionary with column names and values

```
d = { "col1" : "100", "col2" : "'() string with parantheses ()'", "col3" : "2.3" }
```

So far I have the following solution that I don't like (or rather I belive there is a solution using regex only to do the same).

```
re.findall("\([^\r\n]*\)", stmt)[0].split("values")
# from here on I would have to parse the two strings and fill a dict
```

I am not able to find a solution where I don't have to split the string by `'values'` using regex only. My main problem is that the second parantheses string where the values are may contain parantheses themself in strings.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your statement is always in the same format, you can use some basic string operations and `ast.literal_eval` to evaluate the values... Note that this will also end up with the values having types of int, str and float.

```
import ast
import csv

stmt = "insert into table (col1, col2, col3) values (100, '() string with parantheses ()', 2.3);"
pre, values = stmt.rstrip(';').partition(' values ')[::2]
cols = pre.partition('(')[2]
d = dict(zip(cols.rstrip(')').split(', '), ast.literal_eval(values)))
```

This'll give you:

```
{'col1': 100, 'col2': '() string with parantheses ()', 'col3': 2.3}
```

Comment: That looked promising but unfotunatly you partition in line 3 (`pre.partition('table ')`) would work because this would be the actual table name and no keyword in the statement. Sorry, it was a bad choice for a example table name.

Comment: @ap0 d0h - yes... silly me... I reckon you can use the parenthesis instead - code updated

Comment: @ap0 you may also want to look at https://sqlparse.readthedocs.io/en/latest/intro/ - I've had a quick play with it, and it looks like it'd do the job more flexibly but you'll need to do some work navigating the parsed structure and may be overkill if you can guarantee the formatting of the text.

Comment: I thought about this too but decided that I'd rather not use an external library for this.

Answer (score 4):

Why mess with these ugly hacks? Let SQL parse SQL. Here's a complete program to turn any insert statement into tuples:

```
my_insert = """insert into some_table (col1, col2, col3) values (100, 
                                        '() string with parantheses ()', 2.3);"""

import sqlite3
conn = sqlite3.connect(":memory:")  
conn.execute("create table some_table (col1, col2, col3)")
conn.execute(my_insert)
parsed_rows = list(conn.execute("select * from some_table"))
conn.close()

print(parsed_rows)
# Output:
[(100, '() string with parantheses ()', 2.3)]
```

Of course you might also want to consider actually storing your data in a database, instead of whatever you're planning to do with them now. In that case, use a filename instead of `":memory:"` when establishing the connection and you'll get persistent storage.

Comment: I contemplated this - however, I'd use `sqlite3.connect(':memory:')` to not potentially end up with little files hanging around and close the DB afterwards to prevent potentially weird things going on if re-using. Also, you'd want to use a named cursor and that way you can get a dict back which'll also include the columns name which is part of what the OP is trying to achieve.

Comment: and for the headers you can use the PRAGMA statement like "PRAGMA table_info (some_table)", fetchall() and from the returned list of lists the items with index 1.

Answer (score 0):

Well, this is not beautiful but assuming the string you work with will always be an insert statement (based on their characteristics), this should work:

```
stmt = "insert into table (col1, col2, col3) values (100, '() string with parantheses ()', 2.3);"

# if it will always be an insert statement, the following will work.
par1 = stmt[stmt.find("(") + 1:stmt.find(") values")]
par2 = stmt[stmt.find("values (") + 8:-2]

par1_list = par1.split(",")
par2_list = par2.split(",")

d = dict(zip(par1_list, par2_list))

print(d) # prints: {' col2': " '() string with parantheses ()'", ' col3': ' 2.3', 'col1': '100'}
```

If you have other insert statements, please try this and tell me if it works.
Thanks.

Comment: Note that this will give unexpected results if the string in values also contains commas...

Comment: @JonClements True, didn't think of that. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If you really want this, your regex will end up being complicated with *assertion expressions*:

> don't have to split the string by 'values'

```
match = re.findall("""(?<!\') # No preceeding ' before (
                     \(
                     (?!\))  # A closing parenthesis must not follow a (
                     [^\r\n]*?
                     (?<!\() # An opening parenthesis must not precede a )
                     \)
                     (?!\')  # No following ' immedaitely after )
                     """, stmt, re.VERBOSE)
# ['(col1, col2, col3)', "(100, '() string with parantheses ()', 2.3)"]

r = [o.strip() for i in match for o in i[1:-1].split(',')]
d = dict(zip(*r))
# {'col1': '100', 'col3': '2.3', 'col2': "'() string with parantheses ()'"}
```

You should go with the SQL solution for correctness

Answer (score 0):

Use blow code and enjoy it.

```
import re
import ast


def ParseInsert(sql):
    cols, values = re.split("values", sql.rstrip(";"), flags=re.IGNORECASE)
    cols = cols.strip(" ").rstrip(")").partition("(")[2].rstrip(")").split(",")
    cols = [x.strip(" ").strip("`").strip("'").lstrip("[").rstrip("]") for x in cols]
    values = values.strip(" ")
    d = dict(zip(cols, ast.literal_eval(values)))
    return d


sqls = [
    "INSERT INTO TBL1(Name,Age)VALUES('Jon',10)",
    "INSERT INTO TBL1 (Name, Age) VALUES ('Jon', 10)",
    "INSERT INTO TBL1 ( Name , Age ) VALUES ( 'Jon' , 10 )",
    "INSERT INTO [TBL1] ( [Name] , [Age] ) VALUES ( 'Jon' , 10 )",
    "INSERT INTO 'TBL1' ( 'Name' , 'Age' ) VALUES ( 'Jon' , 10 )",
    "INSERT INTO `TBL1` ( `Name` , `Age` ) VALUES ( 'Jon' , 10 )"
]

for sql in sqls:
    print(sql)
    print(ParseInsert(sql))
    print()
```

**Outputs:**

```
INSERT INTO TBL1(Name,Age)VALUES('Jon',10)
{'Name': 'Jon', 'Age': 10}

INSERT INTO TBL1 (Name, Age) VALUES ('Jon', 10)
{'Name': 'Jon', 'Age': 10}

INSERT INTO TBL1 ( Name , Age ) VALUES ( 'Jon' , 10 )
{'Name': 'Jon', 'Age': 10}

INSERT INTO [TBL1] ( [Name] , [Age] ) VALUES ( 'Jon' , 10 )
{'Name': 'Jon', 'Age': 10}

INSERT INTO 'TBL1' ( 'Name' , 'Age' ) VALUES ( 'Jon' , 10 )
{'Name': 'Jon', 'Age': 10}

INSERT INTO `TBL1` ( `Name` , `Age` ) VALUES ( 'Jon' , 10 )
{'Name': 'Jon', 'Age': 10}
```